Overloaded default constructor with initializer list constructor that is also a default constructor and list initialization
Consider the following example that compiles with clang but is rejected by edg, gcc and msvc. Demo
#include <initializer_list>

struct C
{ 
    C(){}
    C(std::initializer_list<int> i = {3})
    {
    }  
};

int main()
{
    C d{};   //clang:Ok, gcc:No, MSVC: No, EDG: No
}

As we can see clang accepts the code while gcc and others reject it. GCC says:
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:20:9: error: call of overloaded 'C(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)' is ambiguous
   20 |     C d{};   //clang:Ok, gcc:No, MSVC: No, EDG: No
      |         ^
<source>:10:5: note: candidate: 'C::C(std::initializer_list<int>)'
   10 |     C(std::initializer_list<int> i = {3})
      |     ^
<source>:6:5: note: candidate: 'C::C()'
    6 |     C()
      |     ^

I want to know which compiler is correct here as per the latest standard.

clang changed its behavior. up to clang-9 it rejects the code with "call is ambigous". clang-10 and up accepts the code.

I missed that you had a default initializer for the initializer list constructor.  Because of that you have 2 default constructors.  There is no preference for wither so you should have an ambiguity error.

@NathanOliver -- it's a two step process, first initializer list is tried and then all the other constructors.

Clang issue reported: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/102157

The program is ill-formed as explained below.
First, C d{}; is list initialization so we move to dcl.init#3.5:

Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements and T is a class type with a default constructor, the object is value-initialized.

This means the object will be value initialized. So we go to value initialization:

If T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type ([class]), then let C be the constructor selected to default-initialize the object, if any.
If C is not user-provided, the object is first zero-initialized.
In all cases, the object is then default-initialized.

This means the object will be default initialized. So we move onto default initialization:

If T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type ([class]), constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated ([over.match.ctor]), and the best one for the initializer () is chosen through overload resolution ([over.match]). The constructor thus selected is called, with an empty argument list, to initialize the object.

So both the constructors C::C() and C::C(initializer_list<int>) are enumerated as candidates as per over.match.ctor:

When objects of class type are direct-initialized, copy-initialized from an expression of the same or a derived class type ([dcl.init]), or default-initialized, overload resolution selects the constructor.
For direct-initialization or default-initialization (including default-initialization in the context of copy-list-initialization), the candidate functions are all the constructors of the class of the object being initialized.
Otherwise, the candidate functions are all the converting constructors ([class.conv.ctor]) of that class.
The argument list is the expression-list or assignment-expression of the initializer.
For default-initialization in the context of copy-list-initialization, if an explicit constructor is chosen, the initialization is ill-formed.

This means that both ctors C::C() as well as C::C(initializer_list<int>) are viable for the initializer ().
But since neither is better than the other, C d{}; is ill-formed.

Why the downvotes? There is nothing wrong with the answer. The answer is clear and concise.
